# text which loaded from mysql server doesn't appears at list view

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to build an android app which receive data from MySQL database into android app.
I followed this tutorial :
http://www.geeks.gallery/simple-json-parsing-example-in-android-part-iii/

the problem appears as  I'm clicking on button which load the data into listview, for some reason the text doesn't appear in that list.
as I followed the code, I acutely saw that the correct data is inserted to the corresponded relevant hash map "oslist".

any suggestions?
thanks,
hanan

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="335dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/getdata"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="load data"
        android:id="@+id/getdata"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

main_activity.java

```
package com.example.aradline;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ListView list;
TextView ver;
TextView name;
TextView api;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<>();


private static String url = "http://www.geeks.gallery/android/android_version_json_data.php";
private static final String TAG_OS = "Android Version List";
private static final String TAG_VER = "Version No";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Version Name";
private static final String TAG_API = "API Level";

JSONArray android = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button getdata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getdata);
    getdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new JSONParse().execute();
        }
    });

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
            R.layout.list_child,
            new String[] { TAG_VER, TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
            R.id.vers, R.id.name, R.id.api });
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "You Clicked at " + oslist.get(+position).get("name"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ver = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vers);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        api = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.api);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
// Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

       pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
// Getting JSON Array from URL
            android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);


            for (int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
// Storing JSON item in a Variable
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                String api = c.getString(TAG_API);


// Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

                map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_API, api);

                oslist.add(map);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

list_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/api"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the list adapter before you get data from the server. At that time , your `oslist` is empty and hence you are not able to see any data in the list.
You have to update your list once you get the data from the server.
The best place is in `onPostExecute()`

In `onPostExecute()` add  -

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
            R.layout.list_child,
            new String[] { TAG_VER, TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
            R.id.vers, R.id.name, R.id.api });
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after

```
 oslist.add(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do all this `ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
            R.layout.list_child,
            new String[] { TAG_VER, TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
            R.id.vers, R.id.name, R.id.api });
    list.setAdapter(adapter);`

in `onPostExecute` after `oslist.add(map)`.

I think it's happen because wen you set the adapter your oslist is empty. and after you add all the data the adapter dont know he need to get refresh.
try also if you have .notifychange() method in the adapter. i don't sure you have it on that kind of adapter